# Data extract, transform and load excel to sql and sql to excel asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, excel, migration

I'm looking for a free and open-source asp.net tool for data migration from Excel to SQL and vice versa, can you recommend one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [import csv file/excel into sql database asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489620/import-csv-file-excel-into-sql-database-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really a Tool, but with OpenXML you can read data from Excel and then write it into any SQL Server.